# Inconsistent moves

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

I have the following mappings in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
" Add new lines and spaces without changing the mode
nmap <leader>j mvo<Esc>`v
nmap <leader>k mvO<Esc>`v
nmap <leader>h i<space><esc>l
nmap <leader>l a<space><esc>h
```

All shortcuts work, but I can't get consistent behavior with <kbd>leader+h/l</kbd> commands.
For example, here is the word and cursor is at **h**:

> Floccinaucini**h**ilipilification

When we press <kbd>leader+l</kbd>, one space gets instantly added to the right and cursor stays at **h**:

> Floccinaucini**h** ilipilification

Pressing <kbd>u</kbd> moves cursor one position to the right, which is unexpected.
Next, when we press <kbd>leader+h</kbd>, space gets added to the left with approximately 3 seconds delay:

> Floccinaucini **h**ilipilification

However, this time pressing <kbd>u</kbd> leaves cursor at **h** as expected.

NVIM v0.2.2
Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the behavior you are observing is the expected one:

- When you delete some text and undo the deletion, `u` brings you back to the beginning of the deleted text.
- When you write some text and undo the addition, `u` bring you back to the end of the added text.

Both of your mapping `<leader>h` and `<leader>l` add a new character. When you undo what they did you will get to the end of the deleted text no matter what motions you used before the undo. I think what confused you is that you changed the position of your cursor with the final `h` and `l` motions in your mappings.

You can replace your mappings by the following to convince yourself that the behavior is the expected one:

```
nmap <leader>h i<space><esc>0
nmap <leader>l a<space><esc>0
```

So as far as I know your mappings are working properly and you can't do much to change the behavior of `u`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Do you know what can be a reason for 3sec delay?

Comment: @asv You will probably find an answer at [`:h 'ttimeout'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27ttimeout%27) and [`:h 'ttimeoutlen'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27ttimeoutlen%27)